# How can I get train data which is used to train default model in stanford-corenlp pos parse and depparse?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to get train data which is used to train default model in stanford-corenlp pos parse and depparse.
Could you tell me how I can get these data?

Answer (score 0):

The POS model is trained on PTB/Wall Street Journal data from and some other extra data that we don't release.  You can get the latest version of PTB (Penn Treebank) from the LDC website.

You can also get POS training data and the dependency parse training data from the main UD site.  That link is here:

http://universaldependencies.org